# Получить сообщение об ошибке

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess

```
ret = subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i /2269.mp4 -c:v libwebp -vf "fps=1/300,scale=-2:min\'(ih,700)\'" -vsync vfr /img%01d.webp', stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print(ret)
```

Если нет ошибок, выводит 0, при наличии допустим указать несуществующий файл. Выдает 1

Как выполнить таким образом, чтобы выводило не 1. А именно сообщение, что ffmpeg не удалось загрузить искомый файл по такой та дериктории.

И аналогичные ошибки,так же получить в переменную и записать в txt

Answer (score 0):

Замени `stderr=PIPE` на `stderr=STDOUT`.

---

И учись читать документацию, где все это описано.

*И в числе прочего написано про `call()`:*

> **Note**  
> Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. The
> child process will block if it generates enough output to a pipe to
> fill up the OS pipe buffer as the pipes are not being read from.